# Should I remove "Adware.HBHelper.BHO"?

Tags: windows-xp, spyware

XP SP3.

Yesterday I downloaded and installed SUPERAntiSpyware free. I ran the program and get a hit on "       Adware.HBHelper.BHO". The program suggests that I remove this.

Can removal of this stop my computer from running properly, or should I remove it?

I did a search and got a number of hit, but all were about HOW to remove it, not whether or not it SHOULD be removed.

Thanks for your consideration.

EDIT: I did a quick scan with Malwarebytes and it came up empty.

Comment: There is more info on the super antispyware site  http://www.superantispyware.com/definition/wizard/

Comment: @BrianA - Thanks. That is the screen that I was directed to by SUPERAntispy when I did the initial research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My policy: Any unwanted stuff on my browser - get rid of it. If I were you, I'd remove it too. I really don't think it should stop your computer from running

Comment: Sure, take your time @Xavier

Answer (score 2):

Like Sathya, as a policy, I avoid extraneous programs, add-ons and plug-ins on my computers. It seems, from your own question that it should be removed:

`I did a search and got a number of hit, but all were about HOW to remove it, not whether or not it SHOULD be removed.`

If everyone is saying how to remove it, it must be something that should be removed.

As a rule, browser helper objects that you didn't add, or don't know where they came from or what they do should probably be removed.

If you are afraid of breaking your browser, you might try disabling it and rebooting. If your browser works, great, if not, you can re-enable it somehow and then all will be good.

You can also try scanning with [SpyBot Search and Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/), or [AVG Free](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffree.avg.com%2F&rct=j&q=avg%20free&ei=7cvzTO-sAoSusAP53M3GCw&usg=AFQjCNGC_5wf_ZlpTvTBmerEaNG3uLMPgA) and see what they have to say.